# Bootstrap scripts and style are not working

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have download a Bootstrap template and embed it on my web application. It works fine when I am trying to access using `localhost:xxxxx`
But when I try to access using same or any `controller(localhost:xxxxx\Dashboard\Patient)` styles and scripts are not working.
Also tell me that in above scenario where i have to register or add references of bootstrap

Comment: Did you added Bootstrap to site master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your paths are off. If you are using Chrome, hit F12 to bring up developer tools, and then reload the page. Errors will be written to the console indicating resources couldn't be loaded. I'm guessing you are referring to them as thought they reside in the same directory of the page (e.g. `<link href="bootstrap.css"...`

Try using Bundles and let them manage the paths for you. So add this to your `<head>`:

```
  @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap")
```

And add this script `Bundle` right before your closing `</body>` tag:

```
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

These refer to a `Bundle`s of CSS and Javascript files. Open up `/App_Start/BundleCondif.cs` and add these `Bundle`s:

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrap").Include(
                 "~/Content/bootstrap.css", 
                 "~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css"));
```

Note the paths, your `bootstrap.js` needs to reside in `/Scripts/` and your CSS files need to reside in `/CSS/`

Comment: Thanks to all But 

I have solved this problem by inserting ~/ in all references

**Before**

 <link href="css/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

**After** 

<link href="~/css/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: Excellent. Instead of relative references that break as your pages are placed in various directories in your hierarchy, the tilde will resolve to an absolute path. However, I do recommend you look at bundling. In additional to centralizing and logically organizing your references, it will take care of pathing (with the tilde, of course) and also minification which is an optimization for your site. ref: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Comment: No problem, feel free to mark my answer if it helped you :)